# Print a pattern without using the row variable for iterating the inner loop

Tags: c++, loops, iteration

Printing the following pattern:

```
4 (input)
1   
2   3   
3   4   5   
4   5   6   7
```

The general approach of the following code would be:

```
int main ()
{
    int row = 1, col, count, N;
    input N;
    while(row <=N) {
        col = 1; count = row ;
        while(col<=row){
            print count;
            col++; count++;
        }
        row++; newline;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I wanted to print the same pattern without using row as input to count. For that, my general thought process was to record the last element in every row and then produce the same as first element in the next row.

I took 'k' as a variable to record the last element value in each row; then the pseudo-code for it was the following:

```
int main ()
{
    int row = 1,k =1, col, count, N;
    input N;
    while(row <=N) {
        col = 1; count = k;
        while(col<=row){
            print count;
            col++; k = count; count++;
        }
        row++; newline;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this gives me the following pattern:

```
4 (input)
1   
1   2   
2   3   4   
4   5   6   7
```

Can somebody help me out for printing the original pattern without using row variable as input to count?

Comment: "But I wanted to print the same pattern without using row as input to count" Why? Why do you want to make something simple complicated?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution, though I am not very confident of it. It works, but if there is an efficient way of solving this one, please do mention it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i = 1, j, iter, k=1, N;
    cin>>N;
    while(i<=N){
        j = 1; iter = k; 
        while(j<=i){
            cout<<iter<<" ";
            if(j==2){k = iter;}
            iter ++; j ++;
        }
        if(j==2){k = iter;}
        i++; cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` is not valid C.  Post is tagged C.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be learning C++, I thought I would put you on a better path, showing you could have:

- No unnecessary variables.
- Better names for the necessary variables (`r` standing for row instead of `i`, `c` standing for column instead of `j`).
- Tighter scope for the necessary variables (they are not declared, unitialized, too early and go out of scope as soon as they are no more needed).
- Clearer loops (variable initialization, exit condition and increment kept together, unlike what `while` does).
- Better text formatting provided in the STL.
- No artificial constraint to turn a simple code into a complicated one.

Try to keep the above points in mind when coding, so you can read/understand code several years old.
Anyway, the result would be in the lines of this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    int n; std::cin >> n;
    for (int r = 1; r <= n; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < r; ++c)
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << (r + c);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```